# find method giving wrong answer in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, find, c++14

In the following code we have to first calculate the weights of uniform substrings present in our strings . Uniform sub strings are those which contain just one character like "a" or "aaa". The weight of the character is defined as a-1 b-2......z-26.

After calculating the weights of all the valid uniform substrings we will be given with various queries and we have to check whether the given no. is the array or not.

Here is the link of the code and corresponding output to it:
https://www.ideone.com/pIBPtQ

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string s;
  cin>>s;
  int i=0,j=0,k=0;
  int arr[10000];
  int c=0;  
  while(s[i]!='\0')
  {
    int x=(int)s[i];
    x=x-96;
    arr[c++]=x;
    j=i+1;
    int sum=x;
    while(s[j]==s[i])
    {
      sum+=x;
      arr[c++]=sum;
      j++;
    }
    i=j;
  }
  int q;
  cin>>q;
  for(i=0;i<q;i++)
  {
    int val;
    cin>>val;
    bool exists=find(begin(arr),end(arr),val)!=end(arr);
    if(exists==true)
      cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
    else
      cout<<"No"<<endl;
  }
  cout<<"the elements of the array are:"<<endl;
  for(i=0;i<c;i++)
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not provide sample input and actual + desired output in form of links. Post them in your question.

Comment: For future reference: _never_ `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`. Use the public headers, not the internal implementation details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `arr`.

Change

```
int arr[1000];
```

to

```
int arr[1000] = {0};
```

https://www.ideone.com/wIj4vp

Also `x=x-96;` should be better written as `x -= 'a';`.

Comment: Re: "better written" -- yes, but it's still wrong. <g> Not all the world is ASCII.